# Find control in content page returning null

Tags: c#

I have used Find control in the content page to find the textbox in the content page itself.But its returning null.I have tried lot of methods but even though it was not worked below is my code...

```
private void showw()
    {
        try
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
            ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
            // ContentPlaceHolder mainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)page.Page.Master.FindControl(");

            TextBox TxtPId = (TextBox)mainContent.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1_TxtPId");
            TextBox TxtPId1 = (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("Content2").FindControl("TxtPLName ");
            if (TxtPId!=null)
            {
                insertString = @"select [Patientid] as 'Patient id' ,[LastName]  as'Last Name',[FirstName],[MiddleName],[AliasName] , [PHN],[PhoneNo], CONVERT(varchar,DateOfBirth,105) as 'Date Of Birth' from PatientMaster where Patientid like   '" + TxtPId+ "%'";
                TxtPId1.Text = "Last name";
            }
            GridView GridView1 = (GridView)page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1");
            GridView1.DataSource = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertString, connect);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "PatientMaster");
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                Label1.Visible = true;
            else
                Label1.Visible = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }
        catch {    }
    }
```

**Note:**
I have to use find control in content page for that page textbox only not for master page.

Comment: are you adding the control dynamically?

Comment: No i didnt do like that..its was added in design..

Comment: hey @Priya, i didn't get that **Note** thing, what u actually wanna say?

Comment: I just want to find the control on content page from that page..Not from master page..

Comment: Its showing error too Object reference not set too instance of  static field

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Before we can use `FindControl` to get a reference to `MainContent`, we first need a reference to the master page control. Once we have a reference to the master page we can get a reference to the `MainContent ContentPlaceHolder` via `FindControl` and, from there, references to the `TextBox` (again, through using `FindControl`).

### Code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //can be called on page load
        show();
    }

    protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //can be called on any event
        show();
    }

    private void show()
    {
        MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;

        // Get a reference to the ContentPlaceHolder
        ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = ctl00.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;

        // Reference the Label and TextBox controls
        TextBox myControl1 = MainContent.FindControl("txtTest") as TextBox; //your textbox Id here *ex:* txtPId

        if (myControl1 != null)
        {
            //Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
            //Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
            Response.Write("Text is:  " + myControl1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Control not found");
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** `ctl00` needs to be mentioned because, both the master page and its ContentPlaceHolders serve as naming containers.

[image]

*it works!*
useful Article : [Control ID Naming Issues](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs)

Comment: Is that ct100 is id of ContentPlaceholder in master page??

Comment: its not `ct100`, it's `ctl00`; you can see it in browser by `f12` you'll find control name like this... `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTest` And that's what makes the trouble!

Comment: @Victor.Please,i will check and inform you.

Comment: @Victor,It showing error like NullReference Error was caught.Object reference not set to instance of Object.Im using find control in private void show() function not in button click.Help me to solve my issue.I have wasted one week.